# Using C#, How to access to a resource file (.resx) and read from a text file added to it?

Tags: c#, file, embedded-resource

I've added a resource file to my project called CrpResource.resx .
Then, after adding a text file to the resource file, I wanna to access to it and read from it by code.

any suggestion please.

Comment: Resx has some nuances when reading... what is wrong with just using the designer-generated code that goes with the resx? Perhaps with some reflection? Or, alternatively - don't use resx; just include the files as resources.

Answer (score 2):

@Brij has provided the core of the answer.

However, the difficult bit here is knowing what the resource name is - it's not always easy after embedding a file as a resource to work out its fully qualified name.

An easy way to find out is to add this line temporarily to your code:

```
string[] names = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

Then run the program, and you can view the 'names' list of all available resources in the debugger.

Comment: As I see in the CrpResource.Designer.cs, every thing I've added to the resource file is as a property.
How can I use of this opportunity?

Comment: You can access resources directly through their property name, but that gives you an instance of the resource rather than its raw data (e.g. an icon like 'Properties.Resources.AppIcon' would be a Bitmap object when you try to use it. You would therefore have to ask it to serialise to a MemoryStream and then read back from that MemoryStream if you wanted the raw "file" data from it)

Answer (score 1):

```
 _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 _textStreamReader = new StreamReader(_assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.MyTextFile.txt"));
```

See following:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Comment: What is MyNameSpace? Is it the name of the resource File?

Comment: It is namespace of your project. In VS > Project > Properties you will get the namespace

Comment: So based on your last comment, there's no need to put the name of resource file after namespace name?

Comment: No, You need to give in this format:
<namespace name>.<file name>.<file extension>

Comment: First thanks,
Second, I get this error:
'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stream'

error line :
_textStreamReader = new StreamReader(_assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Ikco.Crp.UI.CrpUser.txt"));

Comment: You got the namespace name wrong.  It is your project's namespace name, like "ClassLibrary1".  Use Ildasm.exe, look at the manifest and locate the .mresource to find the full name you need to use.